# using grappelli tinyMce in django didn't work

Tags: django, tinymce

I am using grappelli in django, I want to custom a text editor by tinyMce, then I found there is tinyMce in grappelli directory. 
So I copy the tinymce_setup.js to myproject directory and make some modifies. But it didn't work in admin page. 
Here is my code: class

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('title','content','timestamp','slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    search_fields = ('title', 'content')
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'mceEditor', 'rows': '50'})},
    }
    fieldsets = [
        ('文章编辑', {'fields': ('title', 'slug', 'content',)}),
        ('日期', {'fields': ('timestamp', )}),
    ]
    class Media:
        js = ('/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            '/static/grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',)
```

I found tinymce_setup.js is always direct to the grappelli directory. Can anybody tell me why?

grappelli own tinymce_setup.js directory:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grappelli/static/
```

my project tinymce_setup.js directory:

```
/home/jacob/study/django/mysite/static/
```

it looks like my own tinymce_setup.js directory can not worked.!

Comment: Could you add a traceback for the error you get?

Comment: thanks for your answer. there is no error, the django admin page worked,but it looks like the page did't use my modifed tinymce_setup.js, it used the grappelli own tinymce_setup.js.

Comment: @niekas i reedit the question,add two directories,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find this is problem of the STATIC FILES path.
i got a sulotion about this
add MEDIA_ROOT in the settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,STATIC_URL.replace("/",""))
```

then and STATICFILES_DIRS

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    MEDIA_ROOT,
)
```

Media Class in the ModelAdmin likes this:

```
class Media:
        js = ('/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            '/static/grappelli/js/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',)
```

after all this runserver. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is described on the Grappeli documentation: http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#using-tinymce

> Grappelli already comes with TinyMCE and a minimal theme as well. In order to use TinyMCE, copy tinymce_setup.js to your static directory, adjust the setup (see TinyMCE Configuration) and add the necessary javascripts to your ModelAdmin definition (see ModelAdmin asset definitions):

```
class Media:
    js = [
        '/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        '/static/path/to/your/tinymce_setup.js',
    ]
```

> Using TinyMCE with inlines is a bit more tricky because of the hidden
>   extra inline. You need to write a custom template and use the inline
>   callbacks to

```
onInit: remove TinyMCE instances from the empty form.
onAfterAdded: initialize TinyMCE instance(s) from the form.
onBeforeRemoved: remove TinyMCE instance(s) from the form.
Note
```

> TinyMCE with inlines is not supported by default. If our version of
>   TinyMCE does not fit your needs, add a different version to your
>   static directory and change the above mentioned ModelAdmin setup
>   (paths to js–files).
>
> Warning
>
> TinyMCE will be removed with version 3.0 of Grappelli, because TinyMCE
>   version 4.x comes with a decent skin.